# Eclipse CDT cannot create ()

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a very strange problem atm.
Example code:

```
int *ret;                            //Here can I write () without any problems
                                     //Here I also can write () without any problems
ret = (int*) malloc (throw_size);    //Here it is impossible to create the cast brackets
```

It doesnt matter if I press *Shift + 8* or *Shift + 9* or *Shift + Ctrl + 8*. They simply dont appear. I already searched for a solution, but I could not find anything about it (Maybe because it is very hard to find a matching search phrase). Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the problem. If you type `(int*)` it is not appearing? or something else is appearing? Would a screenshot be able to show us what you have?

Comment: Okay I will try to explain it differently. In the first 2 lines I can create brackets normaly by pressing _Shift + 8_ for example. In line 3 I **cannot** create round brackets! I doesnt matter which key combination I press. For the example above I had to copy/paste the brackets out of another line in the code. Writing "int*" was no problem, only the brackets are the problem.

Comment: So, you press a keyboard combination that usually inserts the '(' character (btw. isn't that usually Shift+9, rather than Shift+8?), but no character is inserted? Does this happen at every character position on the affected line?

Comment: @HighCommander4 the shift-8 vs shift-9 being `(` is a regional issue (had to look it up). Perhaps there is some accelerator conflict in CDT.

Comment: @xMutzelx What region is your keyboard? Can you try (temporarily) changing keyboard to US region (where `(` is Shift-9)? and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @JonahGraham My keyboard got the german layout. Switching to the US layout didn't help.

Comment: @HighCommander4 I can insert all other characters, except "(".

Comment: @HighCommander4 And yes it happens on every character position on this line.

Comment: I wonder if it's related to auto-closing of parentheses. If you go to Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Typing and uncheck "Parentheses and square brackets", does the problem still occur?

Comment: @HighCommander4 Now the problem got even worse. With the "Parentheses and square brackets" unchecked, I cannot create any "( )" at all. Even in other lines. It is now just completly impossible.

Comment: Very weird. Does the problem happen in a different project? A different workspace? A different Eclipse installation? A different computer? Does it happen with other editors like JDT?

Comment: @HighCommander4 Yes the problem also happens in a different project and workspace. When I simply copy the eclipse files onto an usb-stick, the same problem occures on different computers. Other editors just work fine, it only happens in eclipse. A different eclipse version resolved the problem. But I think this still should be investigated because it is unfortunate.

Comment: Agreed. Please [file a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT), and mention both the eclipse version you experienced the problem with, and the different version that didn't have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sent a bug report. I will let you know, when it got fixed or resolved.